# Test-retest reliability: Calculation of intraclass correlation coefficient with random and fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, agreement-statistics

I have a design in which each participant is measured at three days. On each day, participants are measured twice.

The dataset is structured as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
y & \text{Subject ID} & \text{Day} & \text{Repetition} \\
\hline
\ldots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\ldots & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
\ldots & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
\ldots & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\ldots & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\ldots & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
\ldots & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\ldots & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
\ldots & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\ldots & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\end{array}
$$

I want to calculate two things:

1. Between-day reliability
2. Within-day reliability

I though about fitting a linear mixed model for crossed random effects of the form:
$$
y_{ijl} = \beta_0 + u_i + v_j + w_l + \epsilon_{ijl}
$$
where $u_i\sim \mathrm{N}(0, \sigma^{2}_{\text{ID}})$ is a random effect for the participants and $v_j\sim \mathrm{N}(0, \sigma^{2}_{\text{Day}})$ is a random effect for the days and $w_l\sim \mathrm{N}(0, \sigma^{2}_{\text{Rep}})$ is a random effect for the repetition within each day. $\epsilon_{ijl}\sim \mathrm{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$ is the error term.

I would then estimate the intraclass correlation coefficients (ICC) for the between-day and within-day reliability as follows:
$$
\mathrm{ICC}_{between} = \frac{\sigma^{2}_{\text{ID}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Rep}}}{\sigma^{2}_{\text{ID}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Day}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Rep}} + \sigma^{2}}
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{ICC}_{within} = \frac{\sigma^{2}_{\text{ID}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Day}}}{\sigma^{2}_{\text{ID}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Day}} + \sigma^{2}_{\text{Rep}} + \sigma^{2}}
$$

Given that the number of days (3) and repetitions (2) is very small, the estimation of random effects for these terms is questionable (see also the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438541/21054)).

Hence I thought about including the day and repetition as fixed effects.

**Question:** How would I calculate the within- and between-day reliability when the day and repetition are modelled using fixed effects instead of random effects?